# Does UNetbooting need to generate a separate boot config file for each computer?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb-flash-drive

I am trying to boot Linux out of my thumb drove to reset a Windows 7 password and destroy Deep Freeze .

I used Unetbootin to extract BackTrack 5 and it boots up properly on my sys using Plop Boot manager . (for some reason my Asus mobo will not boot it )

Now the target PC does not have Plop boot manager and I ned to boot using HP BIOS , it shows me USB Zip and USB HDD.

I tried booting with both of i , but to no avail though I did get a message "Boot Error"

My PC is an AMD and the taget PC is an Intel Core 2 Duo.

Why does my USB drive not boot up ?

Comment: obviously it does not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing plop loaded the USB drive - not the bios, and that's where the problem was.

You will probably want to try to make the drive bootable using the [hp drive format tool](http://www.bay-wolf.com/usbmemstick.htm) - it flips the bootable property - which windows format often dosen't, and try unetbootin again.